Seeking Improved Solutions for Mutex Lock and Semaphore Waiting in Packet Processing
I am developing a multi-threaded network application focused on packet processing that involves sender and receiver threads. This application runs on a single-core CPU, which adds complexity to how threading is managed. To ensure that other threads do not access and send the same packet before the receiving thread signals completion (via a semaphore), I acquire a mutex lock in the sender thread. The process includes locking the mutex, setting packet->request = 1, calling the send(packet) function, waiting for the semaphore post, and finally unlocking the mutex to return packet->result.
In the receiver thread, after the packet is received with recv(packet), I set packet->result = 100 (for example) and signal the semaphore with sem_post.
Here is the simplified implementation:
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

typedef struct {
    int request;
    int result;
} Packet;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
sem_t sem;
Packet *packet;

void *sender(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    packet->request = 1;
    send(packet);
    sem_wait(&sem);
    int result = packet->result;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return (void*)(intptr_t)result;
}

void *receiver(void *arg) {
    recv(packet);
    packet->result = 100;
    sem_post(&sem);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
    packet = malloc(sizeof(Packet));

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, sender, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, receiver, NULL);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    sem_destroy(&sem);
    free(packet);

    return 0;
}

Given that this system operates on a single-core CPU, I am especially concerned about potential deadlocks and inefficiencies due to the nature of single-core context switching and thread management. Are there better approaches or optimizations that could be applied to this synchronization strategy to ensure safety and efficiency? I am looking forward to your expert advice and suggestions. Thank you!

Correct synchronization is independent of the number of distinct execution units you have to work with.

Are you sending & receiving simultaneously? If not, I would do away with the threads. Also, why use a mutex when you only have 1 thread sending? It seems like the semaphore & mutex are slightly redundant.

Single core thread management is  simpler  - it is multi-core that "adds complexity" since it is a superset of single core multi-threading.  It is academic in any event - you are not managing the threads.   What RTOS are you using?  Generally simpler to pass the packets via a message queue, then the whole signalling completion and mutex issue goes away.  However in this case you have run to completion threads that serve no real purpose over a direct function call.  A mutex is only of use when multiple threads are accessing a resource - but all accessing threads have to acquire the mutex.

mutex lock and unlock only in one thread?
I don't see any reason using mutex this way.
If you want to prevent data changes by receiver while sender sends the packet, then you should use mutex in receiver too. Mutex gives "ownership" of data that is in between, but this "ownership" must be checked by other mutex_lock.
mutex
workflow may be not what you expect
You can't be sure that sender-reciever are working in a queue.
Receiver can be called twice (or more), while sender only once. It will increase semaphore by 2 (or more) and cause double call of sender and so on. You should check if sender filled all the data and receiver successfully received it. In fact, you can use mutex_lock and status checks for this to work. Semaphores may bring you unnecessary headache :)
mutex vs semaphore
one of headaches discussed
you sure you want to do this?
In theory if you want sender-reciever queue, you don't need threads on single-core CPU since it doesn't enhance program efficiency.
Example:
void *sender(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (packet->request == 0) {
       packet->request = 1;
       send(packet);
    } else {
       int result = packet->result;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return (void*)(intptr_t)result; //may return the same result several times
}

void *receiver(void *arg) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    if (packet->request == 1) {
        packet->request = 0;
        recv(packet);
        packet->result = 100;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return NULL;
}

if you want to make sure that the same result won't be returned several times, you can implement other status for packet->request or add one more variable packet->received
